Import Cucumber Result to XRay with XRay Rest API ( Add additional Attributes to Cucumber.json)

I'm using "POST /api/v2/import/execution/cucumber" to import result to Xray.
Everything works fine so far, but I want to add additional information to the Test-Run. Somehow I managed to get Attachments added to the result.json, but I will also have added a test-comment in the result.json.
Does anybody know how this information has to be added in the result.json?
I also would be happy to find a cucucmber.Schema which describe fields which I can use with xray.
I have created a feature File in Xray.Exported that file an used it in my behave testautomation environment. ( I generated JSON output with the cucucmber-Formatter).
Than I tried to import the result.json with /api/v2/import/execution/cucumber using Postman.
That works so far, but I did not manage to add "comments" to the Test-Run.

Currently it's not possible.
You can however use the /api/v2/import/execution/cucumber/multipart endpoint which allows you to customize the Test Execution and eventually add some information at the Test Execution level, like on the Description field.

Endpoint for Xray server/datacenter
Endpoint for Xray server/datacenter


Hi sergio thx for your reply.
I thought it should be easy to add an comment ( since i found There some Option to add attachments).
I Check if i can put enough Information into the Test Execution.

You're welcome. I would suggest reaching out to Xray support team (https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/) and suggest an improvement to support that; I'm not sure about if it's viable or not and how you would report that from the Cucumber/Java code at each Scenario/

Perhaps using a @After(Scenario scenario) hook, using  scenario.log(...) to log information at the scenario level, whenever it finishes. Currently Xray doesn't process this log information that goes to an "output" field on the Cucumber JSON report but perhaps it could process in the future.
I would appreciate if you can mark my answer as correct, thanks!
